# Linux backup files command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I had a problem with my Ubuntu install. I was able to boot from liveCD and connect an external hard drive. I want to  backup my files now.

I tried `cp -r /home destination`, but I get problem with spaces in filenames, symlinks, errors "Cannot create fifo: Operation not permitted" "Permission denied" "Invalid argument" and plenty more. What is the best way to do it? Will `cp -a` fix these issues or should I do something more clever?

I found out that `rsync` doesn't have problems with filenames. But it doesn't copy .so and .a files. Also it is running extremely slow comparing to `cp`.

EDIT:

I followed the advice of John Bollinger and created an archive, because my external drive wasn't ext4 formatted, so is not able to preserve all file attributes.

From a liveCD `home` refers to liveCD home, so one has to use:

```
tar -c -z -f /my/backup/disk/home.tar.gz -C / media/ubuntu/longDeviceName/home
```

Despite sudo, I still received some "Cannot open: Permission denied" and "socket ignored" errors creating a tar for several .png files in .cache/software-center/icons/blabla. I wonder whether it is normal.

Comment: Since when does `rsync` discriminate among files based on filename?  I think something else is going on here.  For that matter, the `cp` command you tried should not have errors related to spaces in filenames, though it might have problems with other things.  The errors you report suggest that you may have special files such as FIFOs or device nodes among those you're trying to copy, and if so, that would definitely be something to mention in your question.

Comment: There might also be an issue with the filesystem to which you are trying to write the copy.  For example, a FAT32 filesystem such as you might find on a preformatted external drive will not support symlinks, fifos, etc..

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't know, but I get a lot of "skipping non-regular file blabla.so",  "skipping non-regular file blabla.a". I just tried to copy my whole home directory.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the disk is vfat formatted.

Comment: You should to format backup drive/USB to "ext4" format because "vfat" does not support some Linux files attributes. Then you should be ok with rsync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to reformat your backup disk with a filesystem that has enough capabilities to represent all of the attributes of your files (e.g. ext4) then preserving them across the backup requires putting them into some sort of container.  The traditional container for this sort of thing is a [compressed] tarball.  You might therefore try

```
tar -c -z -f /my/backup/disk/home.tar.gz -C / home
```

You would recover the contents of that tarball via

```
tar -x -z -f /my/backup/disk/home.tar.gz -C /
```

Either or both might need to be run with privilege, obtained by being root or by using `sudo`.

That will handle symlinks, executable files, and any filename just fine, but it may still have trouble if the data you are trying to back up include any special files, such as device nodes or FIFOs.  In that event, you may simply need to remove such files first, and recreate them after restoring the other files.  You can identify such files via `find`:

```
find /home -not -type f -not -type d -not -type l
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. Yes, I already have data on this drive, so I wouldn't want to reformat it now. Will this approach work if my "home" is half a terrabyte? I thought having huge single files can be a problem.

Comment: @Noida, you *really* ought to put things like that into your question.  A huge single file would probably not be an issue for Linux or for any of the standard Linux filesystems, but my understanding is that vfat does not support individual files longer than 4GB.

Comment: @Noida, no, I mean "-C / home", exactly as I wrote, with spaces on both sides of the `/`.  That's a combination of `-C /`, which says to make `/` the working directory, and then to archive the contents of `home`, which is evaluated relative to the working directory.  Tar will ordinarily strip leading `/` characters from file names anyway; I prefer instead to write the command as I did to make that explicit.

Comment: sorry, John :) I thought it would be clear that it is quite big. So what is the best thing to do - get a hard drive and format it as ext4? And then make a tarball or just plain copy-paste?

Comment: It seems that the bottom line is this: the filesystem of the disk you want to use for backup will not support the attributes of your files, and will not support a single archive containing all your files.  It therefore is not well suited to the task as you are presenting it.  You could perhaps come up with an alternative that packages your files into a bunch of individial sub-4GB-archives, but you're talking about dozens of such files.  My recommendation would be to get another disk that you can dedicate to this purpose, and format it with ext4.

Comment: @Noidea, Furthermore, having formatted the disk with ext4, I'd consider going back to `rsync` to make the backup; specifically, `rsync -aAXS /home /backup/disk`.  Yes, it will be slower than `cp`, but it is safer, and it will do the right thing both with symlinks and with any special files that may be present.  You may, again, need to do this with privilege.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Plus it will n times faster once the initial copy is made if making incremental backups

Comment: @RolfofSaxony, I had supposed that this was going to be a one-time thing, but you're quite right that `rsync` will be more efficient for updating the backup if ever that is done.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks a s lot, I made the archive! From a liveCD one has to choose `media/ubuntu/deviceName/home` instead of `home`. Creating the archive I got weird errors for some `.png` images is cache. I think `.png` image shouldn't cause errors like `socket ignored`. I wonder whether is it something malignant.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer does not backup / recover file permission. 
You should use parameter "p" while backing up and while recovering.
Also you might want to recover to specific folder and then move things around to not overwrite files you might want to keep.

"/" on the end of the command stands for backing up entire system:

```
sudo tar -cvpzf /backupfolder/backup.tar.gz --exclude=/mnt /
sudo mkdir /recover_v1.1
sudo tar -xvpzf backup.tar.gz -C /recover_v1.1

... // replacing whatever you need manually
```

Manually replace files you need to recover and keep those you want to keep.

- -x extract
- -p include permissions
- -v verbose will show you the files name while working
- -z compression
- -f name the file

You might want to setup cron jobs to run backup automatically.